# MDX - calculate one date dimension from another date dimension

Tags: date, mdx, dimension

I have a fact table that has 2 dates `Invoice Date` and `Accounting Current Date`. In order to get requested Revenue value I need to use combination of these two dates. For example, if I need YTD Revenue I need to select it like this:

*(Note: I am writing SQL query because I am more familiar with it)*

```
SELECT Revenue
FROM
Fact_Revenue
WHERE
Invoice_Date <= '2011-10-22'
and AccountingCurrent >= '2011-01'
and AccountingCurrent <= '2011-10'
```

Besides Revenue, this fact tables has other information that I also need, but for calculating this other data I don't need `Accounting Current Date`. So my idea is to use only 1 date (`Invoice Date`) in main MDX query (so that I can grab as many data with 1 query as I can) and for calculating Revenue I would like to use Calculated Member and in there I would like to associate `Accounting Current Date` with selected `Invoice Date`.

For example

```
SELECT {[Measure].[RevenueYTD], 
[Measure].[RevenueMTD], 
[Measure].[NumberOfInvoices], 
[Measure].[NumberOfPolicies]} 
ON COLUMNS, 
{[People].Members} ON ROWS 
FROM [Cube]
WHERE
[Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Date].&[2011-10-22]
```

In this case, `[Measure].[RevenueYTD]` and `[Measure].[RevenueMTD]` need to be limited by `Accounting Current Date` and `Invoice Date` must be lower than the date from the query. On the other hand, I need `[Measure].[NumberOfInvoices]` and `[Measure].[NumberOfPolicies]` for particual Invoice Date (or MTD Date, whatever), but without involvemenet of `Accounting Current Date`

Calculated member query should do something like this (this is more like algorithm):

```
ROUND(
    SUM(
        YTD([Accounting Current Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember), 
        [Measures].[Revenue]
        ),
    2)
WHERE [Invoice Current Date].[Date Hierarchy] < [Invoice Current Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember
```

Comment: don't understand do you mind rephrasing your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Navigating from one dimension to another is not something trivial in MDX. In theory dimensions are independent so standard language is missing functions for doing this. You can use [StrToMember MDX function](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/StrToMember.html) but it's slow and a bit strange.

For your filters, let's start with the first one :

```
Invoice_Date <= '2011-10-22'
```

In MDX we'll have to create a set with the members matching the expression. This can be done using the Range set operator :

```
NULL:[Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Date].&[2011-10-22]
```

The other filter is easy to guess :

```
AccountingCurrent >= '2011-01' and AccountingCurrent <= '2011-10'
```

MDX version :

```
[Accounting Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Date].&[2011-01-31]:[Accounting Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Date].&[2011-10-30]
```

It's also possible using [Filter MDX function](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Filter.html) if your need different type of filters.

Now we need to take the pieces and build the query. One possible solution is using a set slicer and overwritting the values when you don't want the filter to be applied :

```
 WITH 
   // here we're changing the 'selection' from the where clause
   MEMBER [Measure].[NumberOfInvoices II] AS ([Accounting Date].[Date Hierarchy].defaultmember,[Measure].[NumberOfInvoices])
 SELECT
   .. axis here [Measure].[RevenueYTD] will be applying the filters defined in the where clause
 FROM MyCube
 WHERE {[Accounting Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Date].&[2011-01-31]:[Accounting Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Date].&[2011-10-30]}
```

Comment: Can this query be used for Calculated Member or it's standalone query? What I need is to apply this to Calculated member. If this is intended to go for Calculated Member where do I put this query? Anywhere I try it throws error that WITH can't be used... Thanks for your reply!

Comment: What OLAP server are you using ?

Comment: As a calculated member is a bit more tricky.. give me a bit of time ;-)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your will to help me even if you don't manage to do it :)